# combobox with items from a different database than the bound data source

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, combobox, sql-server-ce

I am trying to use a combobox in a windows form for windows CE mobile device with sql server compact installed. I am using visual studio 2008.
  I have two sdf databases - MobileArticles.sdf and MobileOrders.sdf
MobileArticles.sdf has a table Articles(name, weight,barcode,...) and a table Clients(ClientID)
MobileOrders.sdf has only one table Orders (OrderID, ClientID, name, weight, barcode, amount,...)
MyForm has textboxes for all the fields of the Orders table except for ClienID, which is a combobox.

I can not bind the combobox so that it shows the values from the MobileArticles.sdf->Clients->ClientID field and in the same time to Insert the ClientId in the MobileOrders.sdf ->Orders with the new record.

I suppose the answer is very simple but i couldn't find it. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create a view in MobileArticles.sdf of the data in MobileOrders.sdf

That would mean you would only need to connect to a single database.